# Python Upload PDF through API

Tags: python

I am trying to POST a .pdf file to an API. Through the following code:

```
from espo_api_client import EspoAPI
import base64

binary_file = open('data/GetReport.pdf', 'rb')
binary_file_data = binary_file.read()
base64_encoded_data = base64.b64encode(binary_file_data)


dataPush = {
    "name": "GetReport.pdf",
    "type": 'application/pdf',
    "role": "Attachment",
    "relatedType": "EventIndex",
    "field": "document", 
    "file": (f'data:application/pdf;base64,{base}'),
}

push = client.request('POST', 'Attachment', dataPush)
```

The .pdf file is successfully uploaded, but when I attempt to view the PDF on the server its blank. Does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong

Comment: What module are you using? Please add relevant `import`(s) to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to decode the data when you send it, this snippet should work

```
from espo_api_client import EspoAPI
import base64

binary_file = open('data/GetReport.pdf', 'rb')
binary_file_data = binary_file.read()
base64_encoded_data = base64.b64encode(binary_file_data)


dataPush = {
    "name": "GetReport.pdf",
    "type": 'application/pdf',
    "role": "Attachment",
    "relatedType": "EventIndex",
    "field": "document", 
    "file": (f'data:application/pdf;base64,{base64_encoded_data.decode()}'),
}

push = client.request('POST', 'Attachment', dataPush)
```